Ubuntu 24.04 LTS shows an "Update information" popup with "null" on restart. What is this about?
My new IBM Thinkpad with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS shows this popup on restart:

How can I find out what this is about? I understandably don't feel safe clicking "Run this action now", but I don't know how to resolve this so the dialog box no longer pops up. Thanks in advance!

same issue, updated from ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. to 24.04
